# C2DM Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android

I had a working C2DM application. 
I reused the same package name when creating a new C2DM application.

It works except now the BroadcastReceiver doesn't get called when the application is not running. That is to say it all works if I run the application and send it C2DM messages. But after a force quit the BroadcastReceiver is no longer called.

I have looked at a lot of examples and compared everything in my old manifest to the new one. Paying extra attention to package names used in categories, Intent Services, etc..

Question: Is there a common C2DM coding/config mistake that results in the BroadcastReceiver not being called after an app is force quit?

I do get this log cat when I send a C2DM message after force quit of my application:

01-11 00:54:43.580: WARN/GTalkService(286): [DataMsgMgr] broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE cat=[com.aawwpcd.pcd3] (has extras) }

I get one of those for each C2DM message I send to the device after force quitting the application.

It looks like the intent is coming in but not being passed to my BroadcastReceiver.

Edit:

Here are the relavant bits from the Manifest and BroadcastReceiver:

**BroadcastReciever**

```
package com.aawwpcd.pcd3.c2dm;

import ...

public class C2DMBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public IBinder peekService(Context myContext, Intent service) {
        return super.peekService(myContext, service);
    }

    public C2DMBroadcastReceiver() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    ...

    }

}
```

**Manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.aawwpcd.pcd3"
      android:versionCode="250"
      android:versionName="ICSPCD3">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="13"
          android:targetSdkVersion="14"/>

<permission android:name="com.aawwpcd.pcd3.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.aawwpcd.pcd3.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

<application android:name=".PCD3Application"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:icon="@drawable/pcdlauncher"
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo">

    <activity android:name=".honeycombpcd3.FullScheduleActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_namefull"
            >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <!-- Only C2DM servers can send messages for the app. If permission is not
    set - any other app can generate it -->
    <receiver android:name=".c2dm.C2DMBroadcastReceiver"
              android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">

        <!-- Receive the actual message -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <category android:name="com.aawwpcd.pcd3"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- Receive the registration id -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
            <category android:name="com.aawwpcd.pcd3"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Edit: Could this be something new in 3.x ? As stated above my problems started with this new application - written for 3.x. What I want is for the C2DM to call the BroadcastReceiver even when the application is not running. I am not seeing that. Could it be a 3.x change? It worked this way before on 2.3.x phones and I can't find anything I am doing different. It will be a hassle to write the test code to prove this but that's next I guess.

Edit:
Seems related to Force Quit. I don't have any problem when I re-install the .apk and then send the device a c2dm message; the Broadcast receiver picks it up. In this case the application was not already running when the C2DM came in yet everything worked as expected. The only problem I am having is after I force quit an application. C2DM messages after that are not picked up by the BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: Provide `<receiver ... />` tag of your manifest and package of your receiver class

Comment: Same problem and I've tried a bunch of things to fix it. Appreciate you noting that it's only after a force-close

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7108611

And at Android 3.1 release notes http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols

As of 3.1,
Force stopped apps no longer get restarted by C2DM by default.
There is a new flag for requesting a restart after force-close.

Comment: What if I receive same result after device reboot?

Answer (score 1):

Have you been monitoring logcat after you "force quit" your receiver a few times? It is likely that you will see a "Bad Process" message implying that your receiver has crashed too many times and Android will no longer send it intents. Restarting the phone / reinstalling the application fixes this problem as you implied in your edit.

Comment: There is no "Bad Process" message. I am getting consistent behavior: it works unless I force quit the application. By working I mean that C2DM messages are picked up by the BroadcastReceiver, regardless of whether or not the application is already running, until I force quit it; after a force quit the C2DM messages are not delivered to the BroadcastReceiver.

Answer (score 1):

Just add below flag to your pending intent which you are creating for generating push notification.

intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);

It should work post this.

Comment: This worked for me. Also had to run the app without the debugger, even if you force quit it afterwards but this may only apply to Xamarin Android people.

Answer (score -1):

If your phone has a Permissions Manager. Turn on the autostart permissions for your app. Google how to do so for your phone.