# Broadcast intent callback is cancelled and causes device to be unregistered

Tags: java, android, android-intent, google-cloud-messaging

I have been trying to see why I haven't been receiving any push notifications and I have narrowed it down to this. My broadcast intent isn't being passed any information due to it being cancelled. This causes my device to be unregistered. I have looked through various questions here and none have seemed to work. I'm hoping someone here can help me.

This is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.amosang.pushtest" >

<!-- GCM Permissions - Start here  -->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />


<permission android:name="com.example.amosang.pushtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.amosang.pushtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home" >
    </activity>
</application>

<receiver
    android:name=".GCMBroadcastReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER" />
        <action android:name="com.example.amosang.pushtest" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service android:name=".GCMNotificationIntentService" />
```

I suspect it has something to do with my manifest but I've looked through it so many times that I can't really see much difference.

These are the errors

```
broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg=com.example.amosang.pushtest (has extras) }
Unregister application com.example.amosang.pushtest for user 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure if this is the one causing your issue, but I think it's because your `<receiver>` and `<service>` tags are outside the `<application>` tag. I've checked a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19090058/6124253), the [Google Android GCM AndroidManifest Sample](https://github.com/google/gcm/blob/master/samples/android/gcm-demo/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml), and the sample code provided in [GCM Android Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start) and all of them have the `<receiver>` and `<service>` tags inside the `<application>` tag. Care to try it out.

Comment: This definitely changed things! Thanks! Now I just have to deal with receiving a 0 status error when trying to register the device. Thanks so much!